# django POST can't return character string

Tags: python, django, django-views

I try testing my server and connect with android client with django. now my code was

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def first_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('you are post method')
```

android client post my server was always 500 response. and if change the method.and use the `if request.method == 'GET:'` It worked... I'am confused what happen ...`'POST` method can not use `HttpResponse`?

Update my question：
and we use java to `POST` my django server.and return error as blow

```
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(Unknown Source)
```

can any help us?

Comment: What's the debug with the 500 response? `Print(request.method)` to check your client is doing what you expect?

Comment: my client use `POST` way. but still not work.

Comment: The view test1.views.first_page didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh !!!! I solve it . and I use django 1.77 and have so many middleware default load!  `#`the middleware will be ok!

Answer (score 2):

I would make your view a bit more robust to make sure you're not overlooking a silly mistake.  Your view should always return an `HttpResponse` object, so either add a return after the `if` block, like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest

def first_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('you are post method')
    return HttpResponseBadRequest('Request type {} is not allowed'.format(request.method))
```

Or add django's built in request type decorator to require a post before your view code runs:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def first_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('you are post method')
```

Then make sure you have settings.DEBUG set to True and see what you get from your android client.

Comment: android client still return 500....  It not worked.  but I try testing use my  browser return right INFO noticed me use get.. but android client still can't work

Comment: Use your second way my browser got a 405.but android client still return 500

Comment: You should be seeing a traceback, either in the response or in the console where you started the dev server.  Can you add that to your question?

Comment: I say..Iam not testing on desktop web browser. at the android client response just 500 and fiald.. how can i traceback? on my desktop web browser weather  `GET` or `POST` both work .It is strange that I check on my apache server log. No error in the log...

Answer (score 0):

Did you include CSRF Exempt ribbon your function?

```
@csrf_exempt 
def my_method(request):
```

Comment: I try it . but android client use method with `POST` still not return 500

Comment: use this way return info with `The view test1.views.first_page didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`